# How can a generic interface reference accept a non generic object?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have code

```
IEnumerable<card> any_object = new card[] { };
```

where `card` is a class which doesn't implement `IEnumerable`. I cannot understand how this code can work ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the C# spec:

> In the .NET Framework version 2.0, the Array class implements the
>   System.Collections.Generic.IList,
>   System.Collections.Generic.ICollection, and
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable generic interfaces.

So the array does (implicitly) inherit from `IEnumerable<card>`.

I don't quite understand the comment about the `card` class not implementing `IEnumberable`. The `card` class doesn't *need* to, it's the array you're assigning the variable to that has to implement the interface, not the values in it.